# Conda environment: libcblas.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, conda, miniconda

I have a miniconda environment of Python3.8. The server doesn't have online access so I had to install numpy downloading the package from the web. When I try to run a script that uses numpy I receive the following error:

```
ImportError:

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
installed.

We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:

    https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html

Please note and check the following:

  * The Python version is: Python3.8 from "/srv_apl/miniconda3/envs/introscope/bin/python3"
  * The NumPy version is: "1.18.4"

and make sure that they are the versions you expect.
Please carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.

Original error was: libcblas.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

However I can see libcblas.so.3 available for that virtualenv:

```
(introscope) [xxxxxxxx@xxxxxxxxx ~]$ locate libcblas.so.3
/srv_apl/miniconda3/envs/introscope/lib/libcblas.so.3
/srv_apl/miniconda3/pkgs/libcblas-3.8.0-14_openblas/lib/libcblas.so.3
/srv_apl/miniconda3/pkgs/libcblas-3.8.0-16_openblas/lib/libcblas.so.3
```

What's wrong here? Do I need any more packages??
Thanks.

Comment: Following off the suggestion accompanying the error report, you should check `conda list -n introscope` to verify the versions for Python and NumPy. I'd also be looking for channel mixing (e.g., combining **defaults** and **conda-forge** without clear prioritization of one over the other). Where did you download NumPy from?